# Rescue won't rescue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, csv, user-input, rescue

I'm writing a simple app that processes `POST`ed CSV files and am testing it against invalid input (e.g. non-CSV files).  I'm using the CSV::Reader.parse command to parse the CSV in a controller method, as follows:

```
@parsed_file = CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]) rescue []
```

However, despite the rescue statement, I'm still getting an uncaught `CSV::IllegalFormatError` when improper submissions are entered.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the statement in parens? like so `@parsed_file = (CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]) rescue [])`. What version of ruby are you using this works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work for me either.  I'm using 1.8.7.  Nothing about this makes any sense to me...

Comment: Does this work? `@parsed_file = raise CSV::IllegalFormatError rescue nil` If it doesn't, does it work if you execute outside of the test env (i.e. through the webserver)

Comment: That always assigns `@parsed_file` a value of `nil` (irrespective of given file), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Its a good test to see if rescue is actually working :) It seems like it is so my guess is that ruby is grouping your operations strangely. Try wrapping in begin instead of parens like so `@parsed_file = begin CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]) rescue [] end`

Comment: Hmmm...tried that, too, and it still throws an `IllegalFormatError` when given non-csv input. This really makes no sense...shouldn't the exception be caught by the rescue statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to monkey-patch the CSV::Reader class to properly handle the exception. I'm still not sure why it wasn't being caught in the controller, but here's the code I ended up writing:

```
class CSV
  class Reader
    def each
      while true
        row = []
        parsed_cells = get_row(row) rescue 0 
        if parsed_cells == 0
          break
        end
        yield(row)
      end
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Note the `rescue 0` after the call to `get_row`, which isn't present in the original. Definitely an ugly hack, but it'll serve my purposes.

If anyone can explain why the exception wasn't being caught in the controller, I'll gladly give them points for having the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a file handle to parse:

```
@parsed_file = CSV::Reader.parse(File.open(params[:file], 'rb')) rescue []
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...though I'm no longer getting any errors with your modification, that seems to have broken the original CSV-parsing functionality (which was working correctly).  It looks like @parsed_file is empty irrespective of file validity, now.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. How about now?

Comment: No, more of the same, unfortunately...it's behaving identically whether submitted file is a valid CSV or not, which is to say that the exception is always being thrown, and @parsed_file is always being assigned [].

Comment: I removed the "rescue []" clause to see what error was actually being thrown; it's TypeError of "can't convert Tempfile into String".

Comment: Ah, it's a temp file. Should've guessed that. What happens if you save it and then parse? If you were getting parsed CSV before it'll probably be the same. What happens if you do `rescue CSV::IllegalFormatError []`?

Comment: Hmm...`rescue CSV::IllegalFormatError []` gives a `SyntaxError` of `unexpected tLBRACK`: `...scue CSV::IllegalFormatError []`...thanks for all your patience with this!

Comment: How about: `@parsed_file = CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]) rescue CSV::IllegalFormatError`?

Comment: @Jed let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1070/discussion-between-justinbach-and-jed)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your `CSV::IllegalFormatError` isn't properly subclassing `RuntimeError`. Or alternatively `RuntimeError` has been changed to not subclass `StandardError`.

Only Errors which subclass `StandardError` are caught by default rescue blocks. To test this theory try

```
@parsed_file = begin 
  CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]) 
rescue StandardError
  puts "I caught a StandardError"
  []
rescue Exception => e
  puts "I caught #{e.class}->#{e.class.superclass}->#{e.class.superclass.superclass}"
  []
end
```

This would explain why I (and probably others) can't repeat this problem.

Whatever the case using `Exception` explicitly should work, and will be cleaner than a monkey patch.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense to me, and I had high hopes for it, but when I tried your code snippet, I still got an uncaught `IllegalFormatError` when using a non-CSV submission.  Any other thoughts as to what might be going on?